# TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

Tags: python-2.7, lista

Possuo um código que calcula a distancia euclidiana entre dois pontos.

Porém, quando executo apresenta o erro: "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple"

Não sei o que estou fazendo errado.

Abaixo o código:

---

```
import math

AP_X = [1,2]
AP_Y = [1,2]
demanda_X = [1,2]
demanda_Y = [1,2]

ap = list(zip(AP_X, AP_Y))
demanda = list(zip(demanda_X, demanda_Y))

distancia = []

for i in ap:
  for j in demanda:
    distancia.append((math.sqrt(pow(demanda_X[j] - AP_X[i], 2) + pow(demanda_Y[j] - AP_Y[i], 2))))

print (distancia)
```

Desde já grato.

Comment: Você ao menos tentou entender o código da outra pergunta antes de alterá-lo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na linha...

```
distancia.append((math.sqrt(pow(demanda_X[j] - AP_X[i], 2) + pow(demanda_Y[j] - AP_Y[i], 2))))
```

... você toma sua variável `j` e `i` como índices. Porém, no seu loop, `i` e `j` são tuplas. Quando você itera "para cada `i` dentro de `ap`", ele não te retorna um índice e sim cada dupla dentro da sua lista.

Se você quiser fazer através de índices, tente algo como:

```
for ida, tupla_a in enumerate(ap):
    for idj, tupla_b in enumerate(demanda):
      distancia.append((math.sqrt(pow(demanda_X[idj] - AP_X[ida], 2) + pow(demanda_Y[idj] - AP_Y[ida], 2))))
```

[Veja a documentação da função `enumerate` do Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Comment: Certo, de que forma eu poderia reescrever para que funcione?

Comment: Perfeito, Leonardo. Funcionou corretamente!
Muito, Obrigado pela paciência e ajuda.
Vou olhar com bastante calma a documentação da função ENUMERATE.

Um abraço.